# how to create model controller and database table using cmd laravel can any one give list of comand?

Tags: laravel-5, cmd

Hello everyone can you please give me how to crate model database table controller with basic function using cmd command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command on root folder

`php artisan make:migration create_products_table` //create only Migration file

`php artisan make:model Product -m` //Create Migration, Model file

`php artisan make:model Product -mcr` //For Create Migration,Model,Controller with resource

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at 
`php artisan help make:model`

In your case, i think you can use
`php artisan make:model -c -m your_model_name`

to get the job done in one rush ;)

Answer (score 0):

Automatically generate relations Eloquent
create mode with relationship (OMR) between tables Laravel

1. composer require reliese/laravel
   2. Add the service provider to your config/app.php file Reliese\Coders\CodersServiceProvider::class
   3. Publish the config file with php artisan vendor:publish --tag=reliese-models
   4. Make sure your database is correctly configured in config/database.php and .env files.
   5. And finally issue the command: php artisan code:models